# Is finding the location of a license key on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have software I bought like Windows (but it can be anything!), since it's something most programmers commonly use (for some reason, go Linux!). Is finding the license key on-topic for this site?

Comment: I would consider that [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) material.

Comment: Please, keep the topic as generic and ambigous as possible, because there are many [tag:license] questions that this could apply :D

Comment: @BDL care to write that as answer? I'm trying to use this as basis for a total cleanup of [tag:license] questions.

Comment: @BDL well, now that that's clarified, care to post your answer?

Comment: Are you asking about support for retailer where you purchased something (i.e. copy of Windows)? That indeed would make another duplicate more suitable, but still answer would be "SO is not replacement for customer support"...

Comment: How about if I'd like to find the license key using PowerShell? I need to find the license keys of all the computers on a domain. You've phrased this Question as a normal user interaction with a product. But it doesn't need to be such. However this meta post goes, it cannot be used as a canonical for all license Questions, due to the way you've chosen to phrase it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, for example, I bought something but lost the key, and now I want to reinstall it somewhere else, or for having a control of inventory so it isn't lost in the first place. Those are stuff I expect sysadmin to worry about, not programmers.

Comment: Seems like https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/, SU and SF would be plausible places for the question (loosing small pieces of paper or email in general, consumer level search for license and enterprise license management correspondingly)... Indeed you can try to pivot that to SO but... https://www.bing.com/search?&q=c%23+windows+license+key%20site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah, I know, it's sad :( Most of those have essentially a tool to do it.

Comment: [The tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info) already makes it clear that general license questions are off-topic, so I'm not sure what else you're looking for here.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery because somehow finding a license, as Scratte comment suggest, seems to "not be about licensing". Argue with Scratte if you like.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery btw, the tag wiki is wrong. You can't program "license servers", you manage them. "implementing consumption of license keys" also seems to contain what many here has expressed that is off topic.

Comment: I find really interesting that people closed this as unclear, and only BDL claimed it as unclear, which I clarified. What is unclear about this?

Comment: @Braiam I'm afraid this question is a bit unclear, and needlessly so. As far as I can tell, this question is related to a recent discussion in SOCVR about a specific question on Main. Linking to that question, as well as the conversation that has taken place so far would make the context, and hence the question, much clearer. If you mean to ask this as a general question, then don't add the [specific-question] tag, but context would be nice.

Comment: No @cigien, that would poison the water on a pretty generic topic: are questions finding where is the license key on topic or not. It doesn't need any example, the abstract question is enough to get a blanket statement. I've done this several times in the past.

Comment: @Braiam Ok, but I suspect not having a particular question to look at made this unclear for several users. I'm not sure having an example *posions the water* as you put it, it just seems like useful information. It's entirely up to you of course, and the question may very well get reopened in its current state.

Comment: Why not say Visual Studio since that's the post you're specifically asking about? Asking about Windows is a completely different thing. Windows is not a tool primarily used for programming... the world's leading IDE *is*. If you want to garner Meta support to use as justification for whether a specific question should be closed, then you need to make the Meta question specific enough to apply.

Comment: @BDL No that question is about legal/fair-use licenses that are applied to software. This question is about locating a string (license/activation key) used in some specific programming software. Two completely different kinds of "licenses" and kinds of questions.

Comment: @TylerH If you're editing the question to mention Visual Studio specifically, you might as well go the whole way, and link to the specific question that sparked this discussion.

Comment: @cigien I did that. However, Visual Studio isn't the only programming tool out there. It's critical to distinguish between a tool used primarily for programming (in fact, exclusively for), and a general use Operating System. It's not really that critical to distinguish *which specific IDE*. The question could equally apply to Vim, Eclipse, Dreamweaver, arguably even Notepad++ (assuming each of those had a paid version...)

Comment: @TylerH: No to what? To the duplicate I suggested and retracted yesterday? Also note that I suggested the duplicate when the question was about finding the Windows license key.

Comment: @TylerH: You yourself changed the question from asking about the windows license key (general software) to visual studio license key (dev environment). Usually editing should not be done when it changes the meaning of a post. If you change the meaning then at least don't be surprised if you find comments that don't match the current meaning.

Comment: @BDL for me it doesn't change the meaning, and I'm the author. I'm just looking for something completely generic and also threw in there "commonly used by programmers" to precisely include anything: from OS's to libraries, up to SaaS.

Comment: @BDL The reason for my edit was because the original version asked an intentionally misleading question ("I bought general use software and want to find the license key") specifically for the purpose of using it as justification for closing/deleting a specific question on Main about a tool used exclusively for programming (How can I retrieve the product key for Visual Studio 2010). The question would receive much better attention & responses if it reflected the question on SO that inspired it even a little bit. As you can see, it has languished since being reverted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is.* The [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states this as an example of on-topic questions

> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

As a concrete example of the kind of questions you're asking about, here's a question [Find out your own license number in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423849) that I think is off-topic even with the above bullets.

Now Visual Studio is certainly a software tool commonly used by programmers. In fact, it might be used exclusively by programmers. However, finding the license key is not about software development. As far as I'm aware, [license keys](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/26227/license-key) are used for copyright enforcement, and other legal or organizational reasons

> A license key is a data string that verifies authorized software product access. This type of software security helps prevent software piracy and gives organizations the ability to protect their software from unauthorized copying or sharing by unlicensed users.

This is clearly related to software, and how it's *used*, but it doesn't seem to be about software *development*, which would be necessary for the question to be on-topic.

*Of course, if the license key is being used for a programming task, a question about how to do that programming task would be on-topic.